# Order of elements in RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames

Tags: c#, .net

In what order does the function `RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames` return the subkeys?  Are they in alphabetical order?  Or are they in some random order corresponding to their storage in the Registry?

I've done multiple searches and checked MSDN, but I haven't found a definitive answer.  Ideally, MSDN would state that keys come out sorted or explicitly state that their order is random...

The reason I want to know is that I want to write code to detect all versions of a COM class in the registry.  They will have names like <base-name>13, <base-name>14, etc.  If the keys are sorted, I could just find the first one that matches, iterate over all that match my search, and short-circuit out once the keys no longer match my search.  Then I wouldn't have to loop over ALL of the subkeys.

Comment: I would interpret a lack of documentation as "there is no defined order."

Comment: Since there's no explicit documentation I would recommend assuming that the order is `undefined`.

Comment: You're getting back a `string[]`. You can easily sort it by using `Enumerable.OrderBy()`

Comment: If it's not coming out sorted, it would be more efficient for me to just loop over all the keys.  That gives me a worst-case performance of O(n) whereas sorting first would be O(n^2) or O(n log n) depending on the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the documentation does not guarantee any particular order, you cannot assume any particular order. if you need a particular order, you must sort if yourself. (The order is not random, but it is not sorted either.)

Comment: In general, I think this answer is right.  It's just that I continually find the documentation on MSDN to be wholly inadequate.  That's why I asked. :)

Comment: In general, if MSDN does not specify, then the behavior is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say this is a definitive answer but while trying to answer the same question for myself, I concluded that it is the stored order, that is, the FIFO or natural order.

All Registry editors I've used alphabetically sort the key and value names. This is not the natural order. RegScanner showed me what I think is the natural order for HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

I don't know of any way to make the natural order match the alphabetical order other than deleting all the values in the key and then putting them back in alphabetical order. However, this order will be broken if a new value is added later because that new value will be added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you cannot assume something if not documented, but many times documentation can be wrong, outdated, or non existent.

So, when using dotPeek by JetBrains, and looking in mscorlib.dll, we see that the following code is used to pull the SubKeyNames:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
Public String[] GetSubKeyNames()
{
  this.CheckPermission(RegistryKey.RegistryInternalCheck.CheckKeyReadPermission, (String) null, False, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
  Return this.InternalGetSubKeyNames();
}

[SecurityCritical]
internal unsafe String[] InternalGetSubKeyNames()
{
  this.EnsureNotDisposed();
  Int length1 = this.InternalSubKeyCount();
  String[] strArray = New String[length1];
  If (length1 > 0)
  {
    Char[] chArray = New Char[256];
    fixed (Char* lpName = &chArray[0])
    {
      For (Int dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < length1; ++dwIndex)
      {
        Int length2 = chArray.Length;
        Int errorCode = Win32Native.RegEnumKeyEx(this.hkey, dwIndex, lpName, ref length2, (Int[]) null, (StringBuilder) null, (Int[]) null, (Long[]) null);
        If (errorCode != 0)
          this.Win32Error(errorCode, (String) null);
        strArray[dwIndex] = New String(lpName);
      }
    }
  }
  Return strArray;
}
```

So - the order will always be using the RegEnumKeyEx function.  Looking there we see that "Because subkeys are not ordered, any new subkey will have an arbitrary index. This means that the function may return subkeys in any order."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724862(v=vs.85).aspx

Which is your definite answer.